# Workflow Field Update Action On Case : Cannot update Closed Date field

Tags: workflow

I want to update 'Closed date' field on case. I am trying to implement this as part of a workflow field update action on case.
But this field is not available for field update.
Why is this so? I searched but I found that it is not a system field.
How to achieve this using workflow action?

I think It is not editable becoz it is automatically generated. Need some help.

[image: I think It is not editable becoz it is automatically generated. Need some help.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closed date field cannot be set directly by you or modified, it is set by the system every time the case is closed. For your specific scenario there is no workaround, if you were importing cases, you could request the activation of audit fields.

[Can the Closed Date on a Closed Case be Changed?](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000199599&language=en_US)